# how to speed the random access of 2D array?

Tags: c++, array, speed

```
arr[2^30][100000]

for (int i = 0; i < 2^28; i++) {

    value = a*b+c;//only a example. In all, value is an integer.
    arr[value][arr[value].length++] = i;
}
```

My code like above. Random access a 2D array 2^28 times to save the position. But this code is too slow for my algorithm.

Does there are any method to speed it? Or how to rewrite it?

From comments, so many people can not read the above pseudocode.

*vector< vector< int> > arr;*

int *seq = new int[1<<28];

for (int i = 0; i < (1<<28); i++) {

```
seq[i] = rand()%MAX_INT;
```

}

for (int i = 0; i < (1<<28); i++) {

```
value = seq[i]*seq[i];
arr[value].push_back(i);
```

}

Comment: Your array is too big to fit in any single computer. And aren't you using it like a 1D array? Any way, unless we know what your overall algorithm is and what problem is it solving, I don't see any improvements to suggest.

Comment: Normally initialisation like this is optimised by either lazy initialisation or block-writing memory. But the second is detailed coding rather than algorithms.

Comment: @VinyleEm Thank you. This code only want to save the index of value, arr[value][arr[value].length++] = i. Other part then use the 2D array.

Comment: The more I look at this the less sense it makes.

Comment: What is your definition of `arr`? Apparently an int can be assigned to each element, but there is also a member `length` somewhere. This doesn't make sense. Please show us some working code.

Comment: Notice that in C and C++ `^` is *bitwise exclusive-or* so `2^30`  is 28

Comment: Also notice that in C and C++ `2^28` is 30. Which as far as I can tell is a meaningless coincidence.  Is really so hard to write `1<<28`?

Comment: If your array is indeed one billion x one million in size then there is no computer in the world that runs your code. Post your real question with your complete real code.

Comment: @gnasher729 oh no, it's only 1,073,741,824 by 100,000. You're off by over 9 times as much. So I'm sure it'll fit nicely in a data center or two. :P

Comment: Well, @Yuanshengliu is pretending that he has run the code and that it is too slow. When the code cannot be compiled, when it absolutely makes no sense whatsoever (I don't have a clue what he is actually trying to do there), and when I'm sure no data centre capable of running it would let him near :-)

Comment: The first line in your question is a blatant lie. There _is_ no array of one billion times hundred thousand elements. And your pseudo code is nonsense: Squaring ints that go all the way to MAX_INT will produce undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing array elements is O(1) time wise. You cannot do any better. Change your algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

2^10 = 1000 (roughly)
2^20 = 1000 (roughly) x 1000 (roughly) = 1,000,000 (roughly)
2^30 = 1000 (roughly) x 1,000,000 (roughly) = 1,000,000,000 (roughly)

Because the array is not dimensioned to a power-of-two boundary, it is going to take some ugly arithmetic to calculate the address of whichever cell you're accessing.

Assuming it takes, say, 100 clock ticks to do whatever it is you're doing to each element, and a 1 GHz clock, you're talking about 100 seconds with NOTHING else happening.  That's about two minutes.

You are calling out 100,000 * sizeof(arr[0]) * 1 gigabyte for your array.  Assuming you're using a language that virtualizes and swaps to disk, you are going to thrash (technical term) the holy frack out of your swapping device.

You REALLY need to think about this some more.

Comment: Yes. Tks. I think hash the value to a small integer may speed it. I will try hash.

Comment: @Yuanshengliu Hashing takes time, and handling collisions between hashes will add even more time. And even if you happen to find a perfect hash, it's near impossible to beat one multiplication and two additions, which is what `arr[x][y]` will resolve to. Concluding: hashing will make your problems only worse.

Answer (score 3):

*Inspired by VinyleEm's answer, my own suggestion for a custom data structure*

Your array is too large for memory. Hash maps and rb trees have overhead per entry, and each entry has to store both `value` and `i`, which already adds up to 8 bytes excluding the overhead. Some custom trickery might be needed to reduce the overhead in both memory and calculations to a minimum.

I would suggest to break the 2^30 entries into pieces, e.g. 2^10 pieces of (max) 2^20 entries each. Each piece can be a sorted vector of pairs of index and value.

Thinking about, if it is 2^15 pieces of 2^15 max entries each, then the index within each piece can be stored in two bytes. The value is 4 bytes, so total is 6 bytes per entry. Or any other break-up with 2^16 or less max entries.

Total memory use: number_of_actual_entries * 6 bytes + additional_overhead (which I estimate to be about 1 MB). [1]

Keeping the entries sorted at all time will be slow, so it's better to just use emplace_back() and sort at the end.

This has the additional advantage that the working set of active memory is kept small: when adding entries only the end of each vector is active, while during sorting only one vector is active. This improves cache behavior and keeps swapping to a minimum.

```
std::vector<std::pair<short, int>> arr[1 << 15];

// Fill the entries
for(int i = 0; i < (1 << 28); ++i) // Whatever
{
  int value = foo(i); // Or whatever you calculate

  int piece = (value >> 15);
  short entry = (value && 0x7fff);
  arr[piece].emplace_back(entry, i);
}

// Now sort everything
for(int j = 0; j < (1 << 15); ++j)
{
  std::sort(arr[j].begin(), arr[j].end(),
    [](std::pair<short,int> lhs, std::pair<short,int> rhs)
      { return lhs.first < rhs.first; }
}

// Datastructure is ready to be used
```

---

[1] Most compilers need to be told not to align those six bytes, in order to avoid wasting two more bytes on padding.

Comment: I'm going to cite this question the next time someone asks me why copy and pasting code is so evil.  You know `2^28` is just a painful way to say 30 right?

Comment: @CandiedOrange As the OP's code doesn't compile anyway, there have been some guesses about his intent. Allocating an array with 3 million entries and executing a loop body 30 times will be so fast that calling it "too slow" makes no sense. My guess: he hasn't copy-pasted his actual code, and during the editing he replaced some named constants with their value.

Comment: @Sjoerd I think your answer is perfect. I will try it. Tks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I think I know what you want. You want to save 2^28 values in a data structure, so you can do a fast inverse search (searching indices with a specific value). There are 3 methods you can use here.

Instead of using static arrays, you can either use 2^30 vectors and grow them as you insert values, or a hash table mapping from values to arrays, or you can use something like a red-black tree. All these alternatives will still take up memory in GB (after all, 2^28 integers themselves take 1GB plus memory for whatever data structure you're using).

Vector approach. You'll use 2^30 vectors. This works because, overall you only have to add 2^28 integers.

```
arr = new vector[2^30];
for (int i = 0;i < 2^28; i++) {
    value = ...; // 0 <= value < 2^30
    arr[value].add(i);
}
```

Hash table approach. This approach only works well if the set of values you generate is smaller enough than total possible 2^30. Otherwise, it's worse than above approach.

```
table = new HashTable();
for (int i = 0;i < 2^28; i++) {
    value = ...;
    if (!table.find(value)) {
        table[value] = new vector();
    }
    table[value].add(i);
}
```

Red Black Tree approach - Note red-black trees are provided as standard data structures in most languages, like TreeSet/TreeMap in Java, set/map in C++ STL etc... You can either use them or implement your own. Nodes in this tree are sorted according to the (value, index) tuple values, which makes fast search possible. Within this tree, you can search for values, or indices with a specific value.

```
tree = new redBlackTree();
for (int i = 0;i < 2^28; i++) {
    value = ...;
    tree.insert(pair(value, i));
}
```